# Is it possible to force Activities to get re-drawn when the back key is used?

Tags: java, android

I understand the concept of the back-stack, so I'm pretty sure this isn't possible but thought I'd ask anyway.

If it isn't, then what is the approach to simulate this behavior? For instance, I have an Activity "A1" that starts another Activity "A2".  "A2" alters the content that "A1" shows. When the back button is pressed, the old "A1" is displayed with the old content.  Whenever "A1" is called again then the new "A1" will show the new content.

How do developers get around this issue?

Comment: Are you saying you want to launch A2 from A1 and then update the contents of A1 when the user returns from A2 by pressing the back key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user press the back-button the A1 activity comes back to the foreground. This will not trigger the `onCreate()` so you can't use that but if you look at the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks) the `onResume()` method will be called.

So if you move the displaying of the content in activity A1 from the `onCreate()` to the `onResume()` method it should work fine in both situations, when the activity is started and when you return to the activity using the back-button.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). When an activity is made visible it will go through `onStart` and then `onResume` when it gains focus. You can load new content at one of these points instead of in `onCreate` if you would like to update whenever the user navigates there.